# (Nextcloud) VM networking issues

Tags: networking, virtualization, vmware, nextcloud

For some reason I can't ping from my Nextcloud VM to the outside world or SSH from my host to the VM. Other VMs do have access to the internet using a bridged connection in VMWare. I attached a Bridged network adapter and a NAT adapter to my VM. 
Below I attached some screenshots of my network configuration:

[image: Startup Screen]
[image: ifconfig]
[image: /etc/network/interfaces]
[image: lspci | grep]
[image: lspci | grep]

What do I need to do to get networking working again?
I would be so grateful if anyone could help me get my data back.

Comment: @Melebius I know about that rule it's just that I can't SSH or copy out of my VM so I had to resort to something quicker that OCR or typing it manually

Comment: OK, I’ve edited your question to show the images here directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `ens33` in your interface conf from the `auto lo`. That might be the issue.